# Recording test cases in excel format from Selenium IDE

Tags: java, excel, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

So as of now, I record actions on the website using Selenium IDE, then I manually write the test cases from that, which I write in an excel. Is there a way I can just get a direct output into an excel file?
I know outputting to an excel file from IDE is not possible, but any ideas on how I could get this done? 
IDE can export the testcase in java, so maybe I could write another program to convert that into my format?
What do you think?

Comment: There is something I need to clarify: Who is executing the excel tescase afterwards? Script or real life tester? If the second, why is recording in IDE necessary?

Comment: Another script is executing the excel file

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Go to Excel application.
2. Select the menu **File -> Open**.
3. In the open dialog box select all file types.
4. Find the recorded test case (with **.html extension**) and open it.
5. You will see excel open it correctly formatted.
6. Now save as a **Excel book or .csv file**.